# PC starts only after multiple reboots

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I assume this might be a hdd problem but I'm not sure. My computers mostly shows "Disk read error occurred Ctrl+alt+del to restart" or "Reboot and select a proper media device". I've changed my boot priority to hdd but still it shows the same error. It's only after a couple of smacks to my cpu that I'm able to start it fine and even when it starts it lags very badly sometimes. I've formatted my C: drive a couple of times but it doesn't help too. Please help as to which part of my CPU needs replacement.

Specifications:
Windows 8.1
500 GB Seagate HDD
8 GB RAM
Intel i7 4770 Processor
I use only Intel Graphics which comes with i7 and not any other graphics card.

Comment: Try changing SATA data cable and power cable and then check. If problem still persist run chkdsk /r this command can find the bad sectors in your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new PC, then the chances of the issue being a faulty HDD are unlikely - albeit not completely out of the question.

There are several different reasons you may be getting this error, but the most common is faulty configuration on the part of the HDD. You have stated that you have performed at format\re-installation on the HDD to no avail, and therefore it is slightly less likely to be the issue.

If you have already checked \ changed the cabling to the HDD, and the issue still remains, I would highly suggest you remove 1 RAM module at a time (assuming there is more than one) and try to start the system with one at a time. This will either tell you if a RAM module is faulty, or if the issue is not fixed, it will rule out the RAM modules as the source of the problem.

If you try both of those things, I would highly recommend you run "Easy Recovery Essentials" below:

https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/

Run the utility as prompted (or follow listen instuctions if you are unable to follow along). There are several different things you will be able to do from within - if one option does not work, it may be advantageous to try another. Once you have done this, you are very likely to have repaired (or at least detected the issue on) your PC \ HDD MBR

If it still remains an issue, I would suggest getting into BIOS via the hotkey upon startup (will vary depending on computer, but is usually displayed immediately upon startup - just pay close attention. Its usually F8, F10, ECS or something of that nature.

Once in BIOS, navigate around to find an option to reset BIOS to default. This is listed in several ways, but the common word here is DEFAULT.

Once that is done, see if you are able to boot.

If not, try the CHKDSK option via the Windows Installation disk. Refer to Google or post here for more info if this option becomes necessary.